# pseudocode interpreter: java while

Tags: java, pseudocode

```
 for x = 0 to 9
 set stars = "*"
 set count = 0
 while count < x
 stars = stars + "*"
 count = count + 1
 endwhile
 display stars
 endfor
```

This is the pseudocode and this is what I've done so far

```
for(int i=0;i<9;i++) {  
   for(int j=0;j<9-i;j++) {
System.out.print(" ");
  }
   for(int k=0;k<=i;k++) {
   System.out.print("* ");
  }
  System.out.println();
```

I need this code to be changed so it uses BOTH a FOR and WHILE, but i can only manage a FOR.

Answer (score 2):

Any for-loop can be written as a while-loop, just move around the components:

```
for (init; check; update) {
    body...
}
```

---

```
init;
while (check) {
    body...
    update;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            String stars = "";
            int count = 0;
            while (count < i)
            {
                stars += "*";
                count++;
            }
            System.out.println(stars);
        }
```

Comment: it gives me this error Feedback: There doesn't seem to the right number of lines in your output. Perhaps your loops aren't quite right...

Sorry! Your work only passed 2 out of 3 tests, and is not a correct solution to the exercise.

Answer (score 0):

As per your pseudo-code:

```
set count = 0
while count < x
    stars = stars + "*"
    count = count + 1
```

you can change your inner loop from:

```
for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
    System.out.print("* ");
}
```

into:

```
int k = 0;
while (k <= i) {
    System.out.print("* ");
    k++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For above pseudo code you can have following Java code

```
String star = '*';
int count =0;

for(int x =0; x < 9; x++)
{
  count =0;
  while(count < x)
  {
    star += star;
    count++;
  }
  System.out.println(star);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a `for` and `while` can be easily converted between each other if you know that:

```
for (a;b;c) {
    d;
}
```

actually (mostly) means

```
a;
while(b) {
    d;
    c;
}
```

---

Just a reminder, in psuedo code `for x = 0 to 9` actually means `for (x = 0; x < 10; x++)`